# Graphite (or carbon) seems to be overwriting data and not aggregating

Tags: graphite

I have reinstalled from the ground up our Graphite server to begin automating it.

I don't know what but I must have forgotten some kind of configuration because now our data only shows the latest datapoints from StatsD.

If I perform a `whisper-fetch` in some metric file I can see entries like:

```
whisper-fetch --pretty FILE.wsp | tail -n 10
Thu Oct 23 20:01:00 2014    0.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:02:00 2014    0.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:03:00 2014    0.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:04:00 2014    0.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:05:00 2014    0.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:06:00 2014    0.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:07:00 2014    0.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:08:00 2014    0.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:09:00 2014    0.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:10:00 2014    13.000000
```

This example is from a metric feeded by StatsD, if I do the same thing in the carbon.* metrics it's completely normal:

```
whisper-fetch --pretty /mnt/graphite/whisper/carbon/agents/127.0.0.1-a/committedPoints.wsp | tail -n 10
Thu Oct 23 20:02:00 2014    9254.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:03:00 2014    8857.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:04:00 2014    8763.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:05:00 2014    8236.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:06:00 2014    9265.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:07:00 2014    8737.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:08:00 2014    8691.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:09:00 2014    8738.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:10:00 2014    8437.000000
Thu Oct 23 20:11:00 2014    5585.000000
```

What is causing carbon to not aggregate and commit data sent by StatsD?

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 StatsD instances feeding Graphite, one of them had zeroed counters being sent and overriding data from the other.

We stopped the second StatsD instance and it seem to be solved.